# How to ask user for loop amount

Tags: python, loops, printing

I am trying to create a small program that asks the user how many students are enrolled in the class and then the user enters the amount. But after that I need a loop to run for the amount of students specified by the user. Here's what I have so far.

```
def class ():
    x = input ("How many students will be entered? ")
    for count in range (x):
      name = input ("What is your name? ")
      major = input ("What is your major? ")
      year = input ("and your year? ")
      print (name, major, year)
```

Comment: What is the problem you're encountering? Right now, you've described what you're trying to do, but not what the problem is.

Comment: You need to convert `x` to an int: `for count in range(int(x)):`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isn't class predefined in python?

So you cant call a function "class". Also use raw_input.

Convert the input value to a string.

```
 x = int (raw_input ("How many students will be entered? "))
```

Define it as a function like so:

```
def doSomething():
    x = int (raw_input ("How many students will be entered? "))
    for count in range (x):
      name = raw_input ("What is your name? ")
      major = raw_input ("What is your major? ")
      year = raw_input ("and your year? ")
      print (name, major, year)
```

Then just call on it:

```
doSomething();
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to give us your specify your problem. But its apparent that you are trying to convert str --returned by the input function-- to int type.

```
x = int (input ("How many students will be entered? "))
```